# add property to NSApplication/NSResponder causes error on macOS app

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to migrate one iOS app to macOS, the code below work!

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myProperty;
@end
```

RootController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 
@interface RootController : UIViewController{}
@property (strong,nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@end
```

RootController.m

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myProperty=5;
```

so I set the similar code on macOS app

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate :NSResponder <NSApplicationDelegate>{
 
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myProperty;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
 
@implementation  AppDelegate

@synthesize  myProperty;
@end
```

AppController.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppController : NSWindowController <>{

     
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@end
```

AppController.m

```
//..

appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myProperty=5;//
```

cause error

```
[AppController setMyProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8992b4a280
```

your comment welcome

Comment: The error thinks that you're trying to set `myProperty` on an `AppController` object.  From the code, I can't see why.  (Maybe use the debugger to see the actual object receiving the message.)

Comment: How is the app delegate created? Is the class of the app delegate in the xib/storyboard set to `AppController` instead of `AppDelegate`?